# select files in folder by geographic location

Tags: qgis, geotiff-tiff, select

In a single folder I have a large set of aereal images (.tif), all georeferenced in EPSG:5677. They cover a "large" `total area`.

I need to load a small set of them, covering only a fraction of the `total area` in QGIS.

As the filenames are just unsorted numbers, I wonder wheather there is an option to select files by geographic location while they are **not** loaded in a project. I work in QGIS, a R-solution would also help.

Comment: Maybe look into rasterlite2 at https://www.gaia-gis.it/fossil/librasterlite2/wiki?name=tutorials . This is literally one of their examples, at https://www.gaia-gis.it/fossil/librasterlite2/wiki?name=rl2sniff

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this would be using pyqgis/python:

1. Create QGIS action or python plugin or standalone script (the last might be harder for non programmers)
2. It canvas get canvas extent and create in memory vector polygon (see [Getting co-ordinates of current map canvas using PyQGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/146314/getting-co-ordinates-of-current-map-canvas-using-pyqgis) and [How to export a vector layer to a new layer and take extent from canvas?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/74465/how-to-export-a-vector-layer-to-a-new-layer-and-take-extent-from-canvas))
3. Loop through directory of rasters (use `os.walk()` method), to get raster layer object or adding layers to map canvas see, QGIS doc [Loading Layers](https://docs.qgis.org/2.18/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/loadlayer.html).
4. For each raster get raster extent and convert extent into in memory polygon
5. Intersect canvas polygon with raster polygon (using `feature.geometry().intersects()` mehtod), if they intersect add raster layer to canvas (see [Pyqgis: "a.geometry().intersects(b.geometry())" wouldn't find any intersections but should. Why?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/168266/pyqgis-a-geometry-intersectsb-geometry-wouldnt-find-any-intersections/168291))
6. Continue looping through raster directory...

If you get stuck, post your code attempt to your question and I'm sure someone else can further help.